# Expressing intervals as a union or intersection of intervals of the form $(a,b]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I want to express all intervals as countable union or intersection of intervals of the form $(a,b]$. I already know

$$ (a,b) = \bigcup_{n} (a, b - \frac{1}{n} ]$$

$$ [a,b] = \bigcup_{n} (a + \frac{1}{n}, b ]$$

$$ (a,\infty) = \bigcup_{n} (a, n ]$$

$$ (\infty ,b) = \bigcup_{n} (-n, b - \frac{1}{n} ]$$

But, how can we express the intervals of the form $[a,b)$ as union  or intersection of intervals of the form $(a,b]$ ??

Comment: Your expression for $[a, b]$ isn't correct. The given union would be $(a, b]$.

Comment: The second is wrong. The union is $(a,b]$.

Comment: should it be the intersection?

Comment: Well, how about $(\cap_n (a-\frac{1}{n},a]) \cup (\cup_n (a+\frac{1}{n},b])$? Does that work for you?

Comment: Any countable union of sets of the form $(a,b]$ must be open 'on the left'. By that I mean that if $x$ is in the set, then $(x-\epsilon,x]$ is contained in the set too.

Comment: but how about $[a,b)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Just using unions of intervals of the form $(x,y]$ will never give you an interval of the form $[a,b)$:

Suppose $[a,b) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (a_n,b_n]$ for some $a_n,b_n \in \mathbb{R}$. Because $a \in [a,b)$ there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a \in (a_n,b_n]$, hence there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $a - \varepsilon \in (a_n,b_n]$. This implies that $a - \varepsilon \in [a,b)$ which is a contradiction.

The same argument can be used to prove that intervals of the form $[a,b]$ cannot be written as unions of intervals of the form $(x,y]$.

**Edit:**

Concerning intersections, you have $[a,b] = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (a-\frac{1}{n},b]$.

Suppose $[a,b) = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (a_n,b_n]$. As $b \notin [a,b)$ there exists a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a \leq b_n < b$. This implies that there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $b_n + \varepsilon < b$. But then we have $b_n + \varepsilon \in [a,b)$ which contradicts $b_n + \varepsilon \notin (a_n,b_n]$.

So $[a,b)$ cannot be represented as the intersection of intervals of the form $(x,y]$, either. Of course, combining intersections and unions will let you succeed as $[a,b) = [a,c] \cup (c,b)$ for $c \in [a,b)$ and for these you have such representations (this was already mentioned in the comments).

Comment: But how about using intersection ?